# MySQLi Connection - Security Concerns

Tags: security, mysqli

this is not so much a "how to" question than a concern I have for the security of my website...

This new website I am building is the first attempt at MySQLi, I am slowly picking it up as I go, however I have noticed a few security issues along the way which concern me and as I don't know much about the new system, I was hoping someone may hold the answers.

1 -- I've noticed a new MySQLi database connection ideally must be made on each separate page where a database connection occurs, rather than having a single `db.php` page and including that at the top of each page with `include(db.php);`- this doesn't seem to work well with MySQLi. Surely though that exposes your database details including your password to every page available for people to download with programs? Security hole or advantage?

2 -- Also in relation to the question above, with all these new connections being run every few minutes or so when the site is busy, how will your database not be overrun or overload and crash?

Like I said, I'm pretty new to MySQLi so these probably seem pretty obvious to you, but to a learner like me, I am yet to know the answer.

Thanks for any responsible replies. 
Aidan.

Answer (score 0):

> Surely though that exposes your database details including your
>   password to every page available for people to download with programs?

Users don't see your PHP source code in their browsers. The PHP is executed on the server, and returns whatever it wants to the browser.

> Also in relation to the question above, with all these new connections
>   being run every few minutes or so when the site is busy, how will your
>   database not be overrun or overload and crash?

For a busy site it would be more like "hundreds of times per second" as opposed to "every few minutes".

The connection is used only for as long as it takes to read the data from the database into some in-memory structure. This is usually a couple of milliseconds. The connection is then closed or sent back to the connection pool.